# Azure Artifacts gives 401 error on publishing a nuget package

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Pushing a Nuget package to Azure Artifacts always gives 401 error. Note that the API key was just copied from Azure portal. What could be the issue?

dotnet nuget push out/MonoTorrent.1.0.39.nupkg -s "myfeed" -k "myapikey"

Output:

Pushing MonoTorrent.1.0.39.nupkg to 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myacct/c7fc868d-fd14-4f27-a36a-8ff9add6482c/_packaging/c2fe5b0f-251b-4017-9848-ed4b906d9fc0/nuget/v2/'...

PUT https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myacct/c7fc868d-fd14-4f27-a36a-8ff9add6482c/_packaging/c2fe5b0f-251b-4017-9848-ed4b906d9fc0/nuget/v2/

Unauthorized https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myacct/c7fc868d-fd14-4f27-a36a-8ff9add6482c/_packaging/c2fe5b0f-251b-4017-9848-ed4b906d9fc0/nuget/v2/ 1248ms

error: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

### Nuget.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="myfeed" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myacct/myproject/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
    <myfeed>
      <add key="Username" value="myliveidemail" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="myapikey" />
    </myfeed>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think that I already answered for this in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61672711/publishing-a-nuget-package-to-azure-artifacts-using-nuget-exe-prompts-for-signin/61679165#61679165

Comment: The solution in the link will not work in non-interactive build machines. These are spun up on the fly by Github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Looks like you're trying to add the credentials into `Nuget.config` file, this is **not recommended** because:

*We strongly recommend not checking your PAT into source control. Anyone with access to your PAT can gain access to your Azure DevOps Services.*

Though it's not recommended, it should work.  For me I use command like:

```
dotnet nuget push --source "myfeed" --api-key az Test.1.0.0.nupkg
```

And the Nuget.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="myfeed" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myacct/myproject/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <myfeed>
      <add key="Username" value="lancel" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="YourPat, instead of the APIkey" />
    </myfeed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

It means you'll need to [create PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#create-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate-access) which is scoped to the organization(s) you want to access with following permissions: Packaging (read), Packaging (read and write), or Packaging (read, write, and manage).

Then it should be `<add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%PAT%" />`.

2.And another direction is to use Azure Artifacts Credential Provider in [non-interactive scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/dotnet-exe?view=azure-devops#on-build-machines-and-in-non-interactive-scenarios).

Run the helper script to install it automatically and set a `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` variable. The value of this variable should be:

```
{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myacct/myproject/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json", "password":"PAT"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try from the Package Manager Console,

`NuGet push -apikey <key> -source "feed_name" ./mypackage-1.0.1.nupkg`

Note the PMC version of NuGet requires -apikey and -source (-k and -s don't work)

For whatever reason, PMC works for me but dotnet nuget gives me a 401.

Answer (score 0):

Goto https://dev.azure.com/YOUR_ORGANIZATION/_usersSettings/tokens and create a token.
Use token name as username and generated token value as a password for dotnet nuget push commands.