# Unable to authorize in Azure DevOps (Artifacts) when building a docker image

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I have Artifacts in Azure DevOps and trying to create a docker build.

- Platform: Microsoft .NET Core 3.1
- Docker (local): 19.03.12

Steps I did:

1. Created a PAT in Azure DevOps (with full permissions)
2. Generated a Dockerfile using Visual Studio 2019
3. Added it in Dockerfile:

> ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS 
> "{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/MYPROJECT/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"USER", "password":"GENERATED_PAT"}]}"

4. After COPY commands added:

> RUN dotnet restore -s "https://https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/MYPROJECT/nuget/v3/index.json" "Project/ProjectName.csproj"

But I receive an "unauthorized" error when I run: docker build . -t mydockerfile:v1

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/MYPROJECT/nuget/v3/index.json. [/src/Project/ProjectName.csproj]
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [/src/Project/ProjectName.csproj]
> The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore -s "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/MYPROJECT/nuget/v3/index.json" "Project/ProjectName.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS \
"{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/MYPROJECT/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"USER", "password":"GENERATED_PAT"}]}"


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["MyAPP.Api/MyAPP.Api.csproj", "MyAPP.Api/"]
COPY ["MyAPP.DI/MyAPP.DI.csproj", "MyAPP.DI/"]
COPY ["MyAPP.Application/MyAPP.Application.csproj", "MyAPP.Application/"]
COPY ["MyAPP.Domain/MyAPP.Domain.csproj", "MyAPP.Domain/"]
COPY ["MyAPP.Infrastructure/MyAPP.Infrastructure.csproj", "MyAPP.Infrastructure/"]

RUN dotnet restore -s "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/MYPROJECT/nuget/v3/index.json" "MyAPP.Domain/MyAPP.Domain.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/MyAPP.Api"
RUN dotnet build "MyAPP.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyAPP.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAPP.Api.dll"]
```

Comment: Any update for this issue? The `endpointCredentials` way won't work if you doesn't have `Azure Artifacts Credential Provider ` installed. Maybe you can use nuget.config way for your authentication, check my another ticker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61726823/10910450). Also this [similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39875460/10910450).

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? Please check if my answer below resolves your issue and feel free to let me know if you're blocked. In addition, here's [one blog](https://huorswords.github.io/azure/pipeline/devops/docker/artifacts/nuget/2019/10/28/access-private-azure-artifacts-from-docker.html) which can help for you, it contains one dockerfile with steps to set the ENV and install the Artifact Credential provider.

Answer (score 0):

**Main cause of the issue:**

The `dotnet restore` command **can't** actually access the credentials you set via ENV.

You can add `RUN printenv` to print the ENV variables.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS \
"{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/MYPROJECT/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"USER", "password":"GENERATED_PAT"}]}"
RUN printenv

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN printenv
```

[image]

[image]

Check the log of first `printenv` and second `printenv` command and you can find the environment you run the `dotnet restore` can't access the credentials.

**Solution:**

You can move/copy the `define ENV` step just before the `RUN dotnet restore` step.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src

...

ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS \
"{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/MYPROJECT/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"USER", "password":"GENERATED_PAT"}]}"

RUN dotnet restore -s "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/MYPROJECT/nuget/v3/index.json" "MyAPP.Domain/MyAPP.Domain.csproj"
```

Comment: @Dimitri What's the result if you set the ENV and then run the same dotnet restore command locally? Does it work?

Comment: @Dimitri Does the nuget feed exist in the same team project in which you run the pipeline?

Comment: No, they are different projects.

Also, the project with Artifacts is set to public and the PAT is generated from the Admin user

Comment: "What's the result if you set the ENV and then run the same dotnet restore command locally? Does it work?"

Did not get exactly. How to do this?

Comment: @Dimitri I'll try to reproduce the issue with latest info above and let you know. About ` what ... locally`, I mean you can [set the ENV](https://github.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/blob/master/README.md#environment-variables) in local machine, run `dotnet restore command` manually in CMD, so that we would know whether there's something wrong with your ENV step.

Comment: @Dimitri Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/dotnet-exe?view=azure-devops#on-build-machines-and-in-non-interactive-scenarios) carefully. `Otherwise, use the Azure Artifacts Credential Provider and pass in credentials using the VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS environment variable.` Apart from the Env step's position, you also forgot to install the `Credential Provider` in your docker container. The Env won't work if the Credential Provider is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and the problem was that I was using wrong username in my `nuget.config`. According to your solution, the username should be `MYCOMPANY`.

Like so: `"{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/MYPROJECT/nuget/v3/index.json", "username":"MYCOMPANY", "password":"GENERATED_PAT"}]}"`

Also, I did not need to use this. When I configured my `nuget.config` file like this:

```
<configuration>
<packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="MYCOMPANYNAME" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MYCOMPANY/_packaging/MYPROJECT/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
</packageSources>
<packageSourceCredentials>
    <Spordrift>
        <add key="Username" value="MYCOMPANY" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="GENERATED PAT*" />
    </Spordrift>
</packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

and my `Dockerfile` like this (notice that I copied `nuget.config` file as well):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
COPY ["nuget.config", "./"]
COPY ["MyAPP.Api.csproj", "MyAPP/"]

RUN dotnet restore "MyAPP.Api.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/MyAPP.Api"
RUN dotnet build "MyAPP.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyAPP.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAPP.Api.dll"]
```

everything worked as expected. I did not need to pollute my `Dockerfile` with a lot of configurations. `nuget.config` was enough to put everything in.